# How to install PyX correctly for Scappy use?

Tags: terminal, python, scapy

When I try to run Scappy interactive shell I am faced with this:

```
INFO: Can't import PyX. Won't be able to use psdump() or pdfdump()
```

(The shell is working but of course I can not use the above ^ :(

However when I installed PyX I then get this error:

```
lstat(./dvips) failed ...
./dvips: No such file or directory
python: ../../../texk/kpathsea/progname.c:316: remove_dots: Assertion `ret' failed.
```

When I uninstall PyX It then just returns to the first error has anyone had this before or does anyone know how to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue the package I was using for PyX was only for python3

Answer (score 0):

`dvips` is provided by texlive (on Ubuntu/Debian, at least). Try installing texlive and see if that fixes things!